# Getting size 0 for ResultsetMetadata.getColumnDisplaySize(i) from oracle database where column may have value

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a requirement where I need to extract table metadata from oracle db. Suppose I have a query "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME". Before processing table data I need to extract that table column information. In order to get that I have written a method like this

```
private void generateOracleMetadata() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = oracleBase.getConnection().getMetaData();
    try(ResultSet columns = metaData.getColumns(null,null, "ALLDTYP", null)){
        while(columns.next()) {
            String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
            String columnSize = columns.getString("COLUMN_SIZE");
            String datatype = columns.getString("DATA_TYPE");
            String isNullable = columns.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
            String isAutoIncrement = columns.getString("IS_AUTOINCREMENT");
            System.out.println(columnName+"     "+columnSize+"      "+datatype+"        "+isNullable);
        }
    }
}
```

Although almost for all case I am getting column size accurately but for few column I am getting size 0. Like this image

[image]

You can see for column DTYP_BIGINT column length is 0. One interesting thing is in database for first row value for that column is null but for other row value is present. Image given below [image]

Someone said that this length is calculated based on first row. I don't know how logical that is. But how can I get accurate length for column even if value is not present.